# Linux Bash: how to compare VAR with characters pool?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the text file with the elements of Periodic table, looking like

```
1 H  *Name of element in 1 language* *Second l-ge* *Third* etc
2 He *Name of element in 1 language* *Second l-ge* *Third* etc
etc
```

(with names of the elements in different human languages)

And I need to remove all the words excluding only 1 target language, and for that I need to know how to compare STRING with array of characters (so that if none of the array letters would be matched with the comparing WORD from the textfile, this word wouldn't be printed).

Could anyone help with that?

---

More details / How I tried to solve this:

The first problem I encounter is that I don't know how to compare VAR with array of characters:
I wrote something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#PeriodicTable1
counter=0
while [ "$counter" -le "$#" ] ; do
counter=$(( $counter+1 )) ;
if [ "${$counter}" == *[1234567890abcdefghigklmn and etc, so here all the characters from the language that is not removing right now]* ] ; then
echo "${$counter}" ;
done
```

1. to run ./PeriodicTable1 OPTION1 OPTION2 OPT3 OPT4 etc (where options are text from the text file)\
2. and to get the words from text as options $1 $2 $3 etc, until $#\
3. and to compare them with the array of characters from language that has been chosen to be saved\
4. and just after (if it would work) I would use ">" to redirect output into a text file

> So If the text in the file would be like this: `1 H Hydrogen Wasserstoff Hydrogène 氢`  and if I would be needed to save only
> Chinese, then I would typed in Terminal `./PeriodicTable1.sh 1 H Hydrogen Wasserstoff Hydrogène 氢`  and would be expecting output like
> this:  `1 H 氢` by removing all other stuff 'cuz characters in the
> words (as the options of a command) wouldn't match the Chinese
> character --> wouldn't be printed

Then I wrote something like

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#PeriodicTable2
for WORD in (and here is the whole text) ; do
if [ "$WORD" == *[straight line of characters]* ; echo "$WORD" ;
done
```

and then

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#PeriodicTable3
counter=1 ;
save={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c,d, etc} ;
while [ "$counter" -le "$#" ] ; case "${$counter}" in
*"$save"*)
echo ${$counter} ;
counter=$(( $counter+1 )) ;
;
esac
```

and then

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#PeriodicTable4
counter=1 ;
save={a,b, etc}
while [ "${0+$counter}" -le "$#" ] ; {
if [ "${0+$counter}" == *"$save"* ] echo "${0+$counter}" ;
counter=$(( $counter+1 )) ;
}
```

but nor a one of these script routines does work

and the second problem is that that if there are need to save a nonEnglish language, then letters of elements would be disappearing; but I guess that with that I could be handling, if for the first problem solution would be founded...

---

UPDATE:

> Solution is still unfound, but I found that task already could be
> done by

1. awk command
   `awk '{print $number_of_word1_in_line, $n2, $n3}'`
2. With counting words by $var and printing only those which positions are equal to their number in line + X*n, where X is the number of words between the lines and n is var in {1..total_number_of_lines}\
3. With tr command
   `tr -c a-zA-Z '\n' < someFile.txt  | sed '/^$/d'`

Comment: In your code, `counter` always contains digits (it is initialized by 1 and then incremented in the loop body). Therefore `[ "$counter" = *[0123456789....]` will **always** be true. I don't understand what you want to achieve with this.  BTW, use either `[ x = y ]` or `[[ x == y ]]`, but not the mixed form `[ x == y ]`.

Comment: Please provide a simple, reproducible example of a concrete (small!) input file and the desired output, and also write how you actually invoke your script.

Comment: I'm trying to put $number_of_option (of a command ./PeriodicTable1 OPT1 OPT2 OPT3) as it would be $1 $2 $3 etc through $counter, so $counter would be 1,2,3,4 etc, but this is not what we needed, there should be $1, $2, $3, $4, so I tried to put $counter as a number after $ to call the $1, $2, $3, etc: ${$counter}, and this string, and not the $counter, is comparing with the [123456789abcd etc]

Comment: If the text in the file would be like this:
" 1 H Hydrogen Wasserstoff Hydrogène 氢 "
and if I would be needed to save only Chinese, then I would typed in Terminal
" ./PeriodicTable1.sh 1 H Hydrogen Wasserstoff Hydrogène 氢 "
and would be expecting output like this:
" 1 H 氢 "
by removing all other stuff cuz characters in the words (as the options of a command) wouldn't match the Chinese character --> wouldn't be printed

Comment: @0x9conc1 [edit] the question and include the examples & expected output in the question itself. Comments are for clarification, not for adding information. It's unreadable and many people won't even read them

Comment: I do not understand. `I need to remove all the words excluding only 1 target language, and for that I need to know how to compare STRING with array of characters` No? Just print the column with target language. Why do you care about any characters or comparisons? How is it related? I do not understand the connection. `if there are need to save a nonEnglish language, then letters of elements are disappearing` When you _view_ the output, it is disappearing. It is important - what are you using _to view_ the output? What program?

Comment: `hen I would typed in Terminal " ./PeriodicTable1.sh 1 H Hydrogen Wasserstoff Hydrogène 氢 "` I do not understand, you want to type the file content in the terminal? `and would be expecting output like this: " 1 H 氢 " by removing all other stuff cuz characters in the words` Great, so can't you just `awk '{print $1, $2, $6}' inputfile`? How do you know which column represents which language? Why not just print first, second and sixth column from the file when you want Chinese? Please post input file sample.

Comment: @KamilCuk I was talking about disappearing letters of elements due to their englishness (and my routine of removing all non target words (if they are not ones from the chosen language)).
And yo! Your suggestion is more than enough (for now) and solving my task! awk '{print $n1, $n2, $n3}' works great! It seems that we will be a good friends with awk from now on :)
And thank you phuclv, it's done.

Comment: How did you plan to keep the German or French words, when they use the same character set as the English words?

Comment: @TrentP Firstly I was considering that by the letters that only in those languages, but later on it comes out (thanks to the @KamilCuk) that it would be better to print into output only verticals that needed; for example, if there would be need in 1,2 and 8 column that it would be something like $ echo "$a" "$b" "$c", where a=1, b=2, c=8, but after that there would be need to add to them the amount of words to achieve the next line at the same columns; but that wouldn't be a problem if only I would know how to put $a, $b and $c into $number, 'cuz $a = 1, but we need $$a = $1 (to call word 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for logic along the lines of what I have put together below.  NOTE:  I have re-formatted the input file, because it is better to have a fixed character (*that would never be used in any field*) as a delimiter.

As an exercise, I created my own raw table with many more languages populated (in a LibreOffice ODS file, then exported with the bars; I can provide that if you want), from which I rebuilt the modified version of your table, where I used the **vertical bar** (**|**) *as the safe delimiter*.

The logic was also expanded to use the first line to **assign the input format values into the "cols" array**, and in so doing allowing the script to adapt to the format of the input file (variations of column assignments/contents) but still output based on the specified language using --language flag.

If interested, the source of the info I extracted came from the corresponding pages identified [**here**](https://elements.vanderkrogt.net/multidict.php).

Lastly, Persian goes **right-to-left**, contrary to others in your table going from **left-to-right**.  The print statement does the **context-driven justification** based on column position, but that info could be provided on a second header line, and parsed accordingly for output formatting.

Hope this addresses your needs!

```
#!/bin/sh

### QUESTION:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234471/linux-bash-how-to-compare-var-with-characters-pool

DBG=0

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --language ) tLANG=$2 ; shift ; shift ;;
        --debug ) DBG=1 ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n\t Invalid option specified on the command line.  Only valid:  [ --language {} ] \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${tLANG}" ] ; then  echo "\n\t Language specification required on the command line.  \n\n\t Usage:  $0 --language [ English | Italian | Greek | Polish | French | Persian ]\n" ; exit 1 ; fi


### Format of ELEMENTS_TABLE
#Z  Symbol  English     Italian     Greek       Polish      French      Persian 
ELEMENTS_TABLE="Elements_table.csv"

### Format of ELEMENTS_RAW
#1            |2     |3___________________
#____|4    |5        |6      |7    |8     |9     |10     |11     |12    |13     |14     |15       |16     |17     |18   ||20      |21    |22    |23 
#Atomic Number|Symbol|Atomic Mass (amu, g/mol)|Latin|ALTERNATE|English|Greek|German|French|Italian|Spanish|Polish|Turkish|Russian|Afrikaans|Sesotho|Chinese|Hindi||Japanese|Hebrew|Arabic|Persian

### Position Mapping for Requestor: 1 2 6 10 7 12 9 23

#ELEMENTS_RAW="Elements_details.csv"
#awk -F \| '{
#   printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|\n", $1, $2, $6, $10, $7, $12, $9, $23 ) ;
#}' < "${ELEMENTS_RAW}" >"${ELEMENTS_TABLE}"


### Match on language position
#echo $tLANG

awk -F \| -v lang="${tLANG}" -v debug="${DBG}" '\
BEGIN{
    getline header ;

    if( debug == 1 ){
        print header ;
    } ;

    n=split( header, cols, "|") ;

    if( debug == 1 ){
        for( pos=1 ; pos <= 8 ; pos++ ){
            print cols[pos] ;
        } ;
    } ;

    #cols[1]="Z" ;
    #cols[2]="Symbol" ;
    #cols[3]="English" ;
    #cols[4]="Italian" ;
    #cols[5]="Greek" ;
    #cols[6]="Polish" ;
    #cols[7]="French" ;
    #cols[8]="Persian" ;

    lCOL=0 ;
    for( pos=1 ; pos <= 8 ; pos++ ){
        if( debug == 1 ){
            print "cols[", pos, "] = ", cols[pos] ;
        } ;
        if( cols[pos] == lang ){
            lCOL=pos ;
        } ;
    } ;

    if( lCOL == 8 ){
        printf("%-4s %-6s  %15s\n", cols[1], cols[2], cols[lCOL] ) ;
    }else{
        printf("%-4s %-6s  %-s\n", cols[1], cols[2], cols[lCOL] ) ;
    } ;
}{
    #printf("%-4s %-3s %-s %-10.7f\n", $1, $2, $lCOL, $3 ) ;
    if( lCOL == 8 ){
        printf("%-4s %-6s  %15s\n", $1, $2, $lCOL ) ;
    }else{
        printf("%-4s %-6s  %-s\n", $1, $2, $lCOL ) ;
    } ;
}' <${ELEMENTS_TABLE}
```